# R: Assign numeric spaces into bins

Tags: r

I have the two following data frames.

***stat_dumps*** represents start and end times (in simulation time ticks). These timestamps show the part of a program execution that the statistics dumps correspond to. There are many other rows each one of which represents a different statistic the value of which is saved. These however do not matter in this question and as such have been removed.

```
stat_dumps <- data.frame(rbind(list(1,101,201,301,401), list(100,200,300,400,500)))
colnames(stat_dumps) <- c("dump.1", "dump.2", "dump.3", "dump.4", "dump.5")
rownames(stat_dumps) <- c("startTick", "finalTick")
```

[image: stat_dumps data frame]

***roi_times*** represents the start and end times (again, in simulation time ticks) of some Regions of Interest (ROI) in the code.

```
roi_times <- data.frame(rbind(list(1,2,3,4), list(40,75,140,480), list(70,95,230,520)))
colnames(roi_times) <- c("roi.1", "roi.2", "roi.3", "roi.4")
rownames(roi_times) <- c("roi", "begin", "end")
```

[image: roi_times]

**Question**: I want to map the different regions of interest to the statistics dumps. I want to add a row to the stat_dumps table showing which ROIs took place during that part of the execution of the program.

For the above example data frames, the result would be this.

[image: mapping rois to stat dumps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bit messy but it may helps.

```
library(dplyr)

roi_roi <- t(roi_times) %>% as.data.frame()
t(stat_dumps) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(aa = paste0(roi_roi$roi[unlist(pmax(roi_roi$begin, startTick)) <= unlist(pmin(roi_roi$end, finalTick))], collapse = ",") ) %>%
  t

          [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
startTick 1     101  201  301  401 
finalTick 100   200  300  400  500 
aa        "1-2" "3"  "3"  ""   "4"
```